# DB2 not listening on its default port

Tags: db2

I have installed IBM DB2 v9.7 on CentOS 6.4. I have a problem with starting db2 to listen on port 50000 (with V10.5 I had any problem, it started by default, but Jazz RTC needs version 9.7). I have googled a little bit around and my current settings are:

```
    [db2inst1@jazz ~]$ db2set -all
    [i] DB2COMM=TCPIP
    [i] DB2AUTOSTART=YES
    [g] DB2_COMPATIBILITY_VECTOR=MYS
    [g] DB2SYSTEM=jazz.local
    [g] DB2INSTDEF=db2inst1
    [g] DB2ADMINSERVER=dasusr1
```

Issuing `db2stop` and `db2start` did not help. I'm new to DB2, any help will be really appreciated.

Comment: Can you post output of `db2 get dbm cfg`? Also, is this UNIX or Windows?

Comment: Yes, this is Linux. Here you go for `db2 get dbm cfg`: http://codepad.org/l1n7Wjj6

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set the DBM parameter `SVCENAME`:

```
db2 update DBM CFG using SVCENAME 50000
```

Restart instance afterwards.

Comment: I know, @MarkZakred. :) Anyway, please remember for the next time that such is not a good question for SO (no programming problem), it belongs more to SuperUser or ServerFault. Yet I was in the mood to answer it quickly before it got closed.